# How to use Class Token in DialogFLow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm using for the first time DialogFlow and I'm trying to use Class Tokens. How can I use them? In the Inline Editor of the Fulfillment? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use class tokens you must add your token in phrases array under  the `speechContexts` parameter in the `recognitionConfig` which is passed as input to the detectIntent or detectStreamingIntent Function in your webhook code.

Checkout these links for reference.

1. https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation#class_tokens
2. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/speech-adaptation
3. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/detect-intent-stream