# How so I pass google speech to text class token in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Does anyone have any code example of passing class token in dialogflow. I have a dialogflow agent that links to a fulfillment in app engine. I like to know how I can pass the class token so that the speech to text will work properly. The class tokens are reference here:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/class-tokens

Comment: Could you refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499354/how-to-use-class-token-in-dialogflow) and this [GitHub code](https://gist.github.com/savelee/73af0549a2cbdc4bd945b90ea2fcfc7c) for Speech Adaptation ?